# Pandas df.equals returns False, Even when True for a string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to return True or False for strings in two columns in the same Dataframe in a new column called 'Match?'.

The problem is, is that .equals always returns False, even when it should be True.

**Things I've Tried**
Running .dtypes shows both columns as a dataobject.
Casting both columns to strings.
Casting both dataframes to strings.

**What the Code is Trying to Achieve and Possible Clue**

1. Extracts the first keyword in a Webpages title (by extracting the first word before a '|' - e.g. *Keyword* | Website Brand Name.com from a list in a column).
2. Removes the Any white space from the end of the extracted keyword.
3. Converts extracted keyword to Title case so that it can be matched.
4. Extracted keyword is the matched to a list of Keywords and return True / False in a new column.

**My Code**

```
# Extract First Keyword from Page Title
one_kw_page_titles['page_title_kw'] = one_kw_page_titles['Title'].str.split('|').str[0]

# Remove trailing whitespace
one_kw_page_titles['page_title_kw']=one_kw_page_titles['page_title_kw'].str.strip()

# Converts the Keyword Column into Title Case for Matching
one_kw_page_titles['Keyword'] = one_kw_page_titles['Keyword'].str.title()

# Compares ['page_title_kw] with ['Keyword] & returns True / False in a new column called ['Match']
one_kw_page_titles['Match?'] = one_kw_page_titles['page_title_kw'].equals(one_kw_page_titles['Keyword'])
```

If I had to guess it's because of the formatting of the extracted keyword from the page title (although it should be a string). Excel =Exact correctly matches them too - I thought I'd check in case I was going mad!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `equals`, try using directly the `==` operator.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_1": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "c"],
    "col_2": ["a", "b", "c", "", "e"]
})
```

If now we execute `df['col_1'].equals(df['col_2'])` the output isa boolean `False`. Instead, if we execute `df['col_1'] == df['col_2']` the output is the following pandas Series:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

A brief explaination:

- the `equals` function is used to compare two Series or Dataframe against each other to see if they have the same shape and elements, and returns a boolean value
- the `==` operator compares each element inside the two Series, and return a new boolean Series